# How to get value from repeating elements in React JS

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, element, repeat

I have a map function that renders textarea based on a number of objects that looks like this:

```
<div>
   {this.state.number.map((item, key) => {
       return (
          <div key={key}>
              <textarea
                  key={key}
                  name='value'
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
               />
           </div>
           )
         })}
</div>
```

My question is how can I retrieve data from each textarea?

```
handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
        [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
};
```

Hope someone can point me into the right direction

Comment: What do you store in the `this.state.number` array? How do these objects look like?

Comment: empty objects, so it looks like this: Array [ { }, { }, { } ] the number of objects changes accordingly to given number

Answer (score 0):

You can Assign index as id to each textarea in mapping

```
{this.state.number.map((item, key) => {
       return (
          <div key={key}>
              <textarea
                  key={key}
                  name='value'
                  id={key}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
               />
           </div>
           )
         })}
```

And get value by index

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    let index = event.target.id;
    console.log(this.state.number[index])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out so here is my solution for anyone who might face the same issue:

Pass the index for the handleChange method

```
<div>
   {this.state.number.map((item, index) => {
      return (
        <div key={index}>
           <textarea       
              value={item.statement}
              onChange={(e)=>this.handleChange(e, index)}
            />
         </div>
         )
        })}
  </div>
```

Then use it like this:

```
handleChange = (event, index) => {
    this.state.number[index] = event.target.value
    this.setState({ number : this.state.number})
};
```